# PhoneGap cordova plugin for Android

Tags: cordova

I am using this example 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

But I can not pass "tag".

Example says .....

`window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title here", "Put your message here");`

Where should I change the code to make it accept "tag" as a parameter  ?

I want to do

`window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("11", "Put your title here", "Put your message here");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `NotificationMessenger.prototype.notify()` in statusbarnotification.js to this:

```
/**
 * @param tag Tag of the notification
 * @param title Title of the notification
 * @param body Body of the notification
 * @deprecated Use the W3C standard window.Notification API instead.
 */
NotificationMessenger.prototype.notify = function(tag, title, body, flag) {
    if (window.Notification) {
        this.activeNotification = new window.Notification(title, {
            body: body,
            flag: flag,
            tag: tag
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("11", "Put your title here", "Put your message here");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It worked! I was changing java code and wasn't working for me. Appreciate your reply.